# Cucumber Runner issue in VSCode IDE

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am trying to execute a Cucumber test in VSCode but I'm getting error: "package org.junit.runner does not exist import org.junit.runner.RunWith;"

The same Cucumber project runs in Eclipse IDE without any issue. But when I run the Cucumber project in VSCode it gives error.

My JUnit Dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.12</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

My JUnit Runner:

```
package testRunners;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/features/cucumberexpressions_1.feature"}, 
                     glue = {"com.stepdefinitions", "utility"},
                   plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"},
                   tags = "@tag and @tag1",
                   monochrome = true)
public class TestRunner_SamplePage 
{

}
```